# Registration Form with only email + password

Tags: django, django-forms

I want a Registration Form with only email + password. I am thinking to insert automatically email in username field. So, for eash user, I will have this:

username: example@example.com

password: mypassword

email:    example@example.com

Of course email + password will be used in login process.

Is it a good solution to having 2 fields with the same value ? Or is there a more sofisticated solution ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a good idea to circumvent [the expected regex validation on `username`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L14) which is `r'^\w+$'` (so no `@` or `.`, obviously). Also, there's a [30 character limit](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L137) on `username`, so lots of email addresses won't fit.

You should write a custom auth backend that authenticates based on the actual email field - many people do this, so you can probably find samples on djangosnippets.

Two things to keep in mind - by default, the email field is non-unique. Also, you are almost definitely going to break the admin app, so you'll need to do some jiggery pokery if you want to use contrib.admin.

Comment: To resolve I can insert random string in username field and "unique=True" in Registration Form's email. Is a good idea ?